# spark-submit: workers do not get assigned to the master

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I try to run spark streaming application with spark-submit on a single virtual machine, in a standalone mode, but worker does not get assigned to the driver.

I keep getting this WARN:
"Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources"

But the thing is that there are no other applications running, and there is enough memory, so resources are not a problem. When I look into Spark UI, I see that application is running, but it is in "WAITING" state.

I also get these two WARN-ings:
"Your hostname, HOST_NAME resolves to a loopback address"
&
"Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address"

I have tried modifying spark/conf/slaves, and putting IP address instead of HOST_NAME, but still no solution.

Can you help please.

Comment: you should post the whole command you're issuing. Are you submitting the job as local, as yarn-client, yarn-master, or... ?

Comment: It is in standalone mode, no cluster managers.

Comment: Have you looked at the spark UI to make sure your workers properly connect to your master?

Comment: they are not connecting to the master, that is the problem! these are the warnings I get:

WARN Utils: Your hostname, datacenter-dev resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth0)
16/03/11 14:09:23 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address

Comment: are you using it on amazon AWS? Your ACL/iptables configuration may be preventing the executers from connecting to the master.

Comment: Nono, it is a virtual machine running on my lap top..

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you probably didn't start the Worker on that machine.
After you started the Master process, you have to start a Worker that will be assigned to the previously started master.

After starting these 2 processes, check the web ui, most probably at `http://<server-url>:8080` where you should be able to see the Master with 1 Worker assigned.

If eveything looks fine, you should be able to submit jobs to the Master.